# como recorrer un array dentro de otro array

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito iterar a través de un archivo json que tiene una matriz dentro de una matriz.
el archivo json es el siguiente.

```
{
"Objetivo": {
    "Paso": [
        {
            "nombre": "Home",
            "est": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "Detalle": [
                        {
                            "fecha_desde": "2022-06-12T00:00:00-04:00",
                            "nombre": "uptime",
                            "fecha_hasta": "2022-06-13T00:00:00Z",
                            "id": "1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "nombre": "Prueba"
                }
            ],
            "id": 0
        }],
        
    "objetivo_nombre": "Pago",
    "Marca Temporal": "2022-07-18T16:44:58.758908-04:00",
    "objetivo": 99999
}
```

}

estoy desarrollando de la siguiente forma.

```
const info = response.data;
const dato = info.Objetivo;
// console.log('dat',dato);
arr(dato);
function arr(infoTODO) {
    console.log(infoTODO);
    for (let i = 0; i < infoTODO.Paso.length; i++) {
        console.log(infoTODO.Paso[i]); 
        for (let j = 0; j < infoTODO.Paso[i].Detalle.length; j++) {
            console.log(infoTODO.Paso[i].Detalle[j]);
          }
    }   
    
}
```

})
Al ejecutar el código me arroja un mensaje undifined.

cualquier comentario es bienvenida.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el forEach, que es mejor que el bucle for. Para cada iteración te devuelve un elemento

```
 const dato = info.Objetivo;
 dato.Paso?.forEach(paso=>{
     console.log(paso);
     paso.est?.forEach(est =>{
         console.log(est);
         est.Detalle.forEach(detalle => {
             console.log(detalle);
         })
     })
 })
```